# If condition for value assignment check in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a condition as below to check the variables `Qmart` and `linearstatus`.
Though they have the values as required, my `if` statement is always going to the `else` condition.  Is there some mistake I'm making for checking these values?

```
var Qmart = "A2";
var linearstatus  = "linear"

if (Qmart === ("E2" || "A2" || "B2" || "D2") && linearstatus == "linear") {
} else {
    alert("it is an else condition");
}
```

Comment: You are gonna have to compare them all one by one, or put them in an array and use `find` or `indexOf`. `if (Qmart === "E2" || Qmart === "A2" ... ) { ... }`

Comment: "E2" || "A2" || "B2" || "D2" => "E2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the if condition to the following

```js
if ((Qmart === "E2" || Qmart === "A2" || Qmart === "B2" || Qmart === "D2") && (linearstatus == "linear")) {

} else {
  alert("it is an else condition");
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for multiple values you cannot use `Qmart === ("E2" || "A2" || "B2" || "D2")`, you need to check each condition separatelly:

```
if ((Qmart === "E2" || Qmart === "A2" || Qmart === "B2" || Qmart === "D2") && linearstatus == "linear") {

} else {
    alert("it is an else condition");
}
```

You might ask why your code did not throw any runtime error. The issue is that code

```
"E2" || "A2" || "B2" || "D2"
```

is a valid JavaScript code, and it returns first truthy value. This feature is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) and is used often in JavaScript. In your case above statement returns first truthy value, which is always "E2". This means that, your code is identical to

```
if (Qmart === "E2" && linearstatus == "linear")
```

and when `Qmart` is `A2`, then the condition evaluates to `false` and `else` statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```js
var QMart = "E2",
  linearstatus = "linear";

var conditions = ["E2", "A2", "B2", "D2"];
if (conditions.indexOf(QMart) !== -1 && (linearstatus == "linear")) {
  console.log("In truthy condition");
} else {
  console.log("it is an else condition");
}
```